# MySQL cursor for comma delimited string?

Tags: mysql, loops, cursor

I'm new to MySQL so need some help.

I have a table in which there is a varchar column which contains comma delimited strings, like so:

```
cat_1,cat_2,cat_3,cat_4,cat_5
cat_6,cat_7,cat_8,cat_5
cat_1,cat_2,cat_5
cat_1,cat_2,cat_9,cat_4,cat_5
cat_7,cat_5
```

I want to create a cursor which I can use to loop over each `cat_` value in such a string.

I have to compare each substring with a set value, and then do some logic based on that.

In algorithmic form, this is what I need:

```
foreach row
     foreach substring s in big_string
          if s='cat_1'
               --do logic
          else if s='cat_2'
               --do logic
          else if s='cat_3'
               --do logic
          --and so on
          end

     end
end
```

I know how to create the outer loop using a normal select cursor. I just don't know how to create the inner loop, which loops over each comma delimited substring.

Can someone help ?

**EDIT:** I need this for a stored procedure.

Comment: Have you researched:  FIND_IN_SET()?

Comment: What kind of logic you're trying to apply? Please elaborate. You may not need cursors neither for splitting nor for applying your logic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a function to fetch the n-th piece of a delimited string:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `string_splitter` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `string_splitter`(
  str text,
  delim varchar(255),
  pos int) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

return replace(substring_index(str, delim, pos), concat(substring_index(str, delim, pos - 1), delim), '');

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

And now the code, which uses that function to iterate over the pieces of the delimited string:

```
set @str = 'cat_1,cat_2,cat_3,cat_4,cat_5'; -- replace this with the value from the cursor
set @delim = ',';
set @numPieces = 1 + ((length(@str) - length(replace(@str, @delim, ''))) / length(@delim));
set @i = 1;

while @i <= @numPieces do
    set @piece = string_splitter(@str, @delim, @i);
    -- do something here with @piece
    set @i = @i + 1;
end while;
```